# Android WebView : Remove pop-out option in google drive/doc viewer

Tags: android, pdf, google-drive-api, android-webview, google-docs

I am loading the pdf documents in WebView through appending the pdf url to google doc api

`http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=myurl`

Pdf is loading just fine but the webpage displays two options - `Zoom-in` and `Pop-Out`. Is there any way to disable/hide pop-out option by sending some param? Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Looking for the same thing but it seems that there is no documentation for the google docs viewer at all.

Comment: Yeah. It seems so. Even I couldn't find any doc.

Answer (score 15):

You can add this callback and in a result "pop-out" button will be removed.

```
@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.querySelector('[role=\"toolbar\"]').remove();})()");
    }
```

Note: If you want to now show this button at all, make your web view visible after applying last javascript code.

Comment: I found you solution useful then an accepted answer, but have you noticed while progressbar is running, it still shows Pop-out option, so anyone can tap on it... and perform further actions. Do you have any solution for same.

Answer (score 7):

```
//initialze WebView
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fullscree_webview);

//set the javascript enable to your webview
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//set the WebViewClient
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

//once the page is loaded get the html element by class or id and through javascript hide it.
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-GSQQnc-LgbsSe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-to915-LgbsSe VIpgJd-TzA9Ye-eEGnhe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-LgbsSe')[0].style.display='none'; })()");
        }
    })
```

Comment: awesome. very genius solution

Comment: It is just hiding the option,but that view is still there. Is there any other option to hide the view??

Comment: @SarithaG : I did lot of research in this Issue and I dont think there is option to hide that view. All we can do is to using CSS code hack we can hide that view.

Comment: Thnq for your response..Can you post that CSS code..?

Comment: @ Jaffar Hi.. I've tried your solution to achieve that same. But i couldn't hide it. i've posted my question with the code at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382984/hide-print-download-options-for-pdf-in-webview-using-google-docs. Could you please check it and suggest me any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sangeetha : let me check and ill update you soon :)

Answer (score 4):

```
mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.your_web_view_id);

//do the javascript enable to your webview
mWebview .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//set the WebViewClient
mWebview .setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

//add this line to Hide pop-out tool bar of pdfview in pagLoadFinish
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
             mWebview .loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.querySelector('[class=\"ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b\"]').remove();})()")
        }
    })
```

**This  will remove the pop-out toolbar which is the redirection in chrome browser**

*Happy Coding*

Comment: this worked for me. Thanks @Darshan Khatri

Answer (score 0):

To strictly not allow anyone to click on "pop-out"

1. Keep the WebView hidden from the beginning by using

   ```
   webview.setVisibility(View.GONE)
   ```
2. Inside the webview

   ```
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
           @Override
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
               super.onPageFinished(view, url);
               webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                       "document.querySelector('[role=\"toolbar\"]').remove();})()");
               webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }
       });
   ```

Simple yet effective! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> 100% working solution, i am using below ans

```
    binding!!.webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            if(url.contains("https")){ // idea1 : back button to exit!
                // finish()
            }
            return true
        }
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {


// idea 2:  to hide button icon & background
    
            binding!!.webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-GSQQnc-LgbsSe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-to915-LgbsSe VIpgJd-TzA9Ye-eEGnhe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-LgbsSe')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b')[0].setAttribute('style','width:0px');})()")
        }
    }
```

**xml: idea 3**

```
<WebView
        android:layout_marginStart="-30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-30dp"
        
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code to disable that:

```
<div style="width: 640px; height: 480px; position: relative;">
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByzS..." width="640" height="480"
frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
<div style="width: 80px; height: 80px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; right: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
</div>
```